# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() while dealing with images

Tags: python

I want to check the gray pixels in image with this code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\KING K\Downloads\sampletel.jpg',1)

r,c,b=img.shape
for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        if img[i,j] < 200:
            print(i,j)
            print("this pixel is black")
```

I am getting error like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-d51057033506> in <module>()
      7 for i in range(r):
      8     for j in range(c):
----> 9         if img[i,j] < 200:
     10             print(i,j)
     11             print("this pixel is black")

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Can you suggest any solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the error message. Implicitly it says that you are comparing an array with a scalar which will result in as many boolean values as the number of elements of the array. With `np.any()` or `np.all()` you convert that into an overall answer.

I your case I `img[i,j]` is an array with RGB values, thus to check if all of them are below 200 you need to write

```
if (img[i,j] < 200).all():
    print 'this pixel is black'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue with `1` (black/white) mode passed to `cv2.imread`.
Try `'L'` (greyscale) instead.